# I want to apply common app bar theme to the appbar in flutter

Tags: flutter

[image]

How to apply same font family, the same font-weight basically entire theme to appbar that would be reflected globally in all pages

Comment: Have you tried `AppBarTheme`?

Comment: No i am begineer in flutter.I did not get how to do it?Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use AppBarTheme.Please find the below code

In MaterialApp use like this,

```
MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test App',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          textTheme: ThemeData.light()
              .textTheme
              .copyWith(
                headline6: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                ),
              )
              .apply(
                fontFamily: 'Roboto',
              ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

While using appBar use like this,

```
AppBar(
      title: Text('App bar', 
                 style: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.textTheme.headline6,
             ),
    );
```